# Are the initial values used for each parameter the same for each chain in rjags? I am using coda.samples for sampling

Tags: r, mcmc, jags, rjags

I have several parameters and do not wish to manually specify initial values for n=3 chains. I am wondering whether RJAGS will give different initial values for each chain. The [manual](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Ebbeckage/Teaching/PBIO_294/Manuals/manual.jags.pdf) for JAGS says that the same initial value is used for each chain however when I tried to get some samples without any adaptation the initial values seem to be different. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `jags.model()` will use the same initial values if you don't provide them.  The samples will differ from each other because of the randomness inherent in the MCMC sampling, so that is not an indication of different initial values being used.  You can use the `state()` function to see the state of your model after initialization, which will give all of the initial values.  Here's a simple example.  When we don't provide initial values for `mu`, they are both 0.

```
jd <- list(x = runif(100))
jm <- "
model{
for(i in 1:100){
 x[i] ~ dnorm(mu, 1)
}
mu ~ dnorm(0,3)
}
"
cat(jm, file="tmp.mod")
jm <- jags.model("tmp.mod", data=jd, n.chains=2)
jm$state()
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$mu
# [1] 0
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$mu
# [1] 0
```

When we provide initial values, the `state()` function identifies that they are in fact the ones we provided.

```
jm2 <- jags.model("tmp.mod", 
                 data=jd, 
                 n.chains=2, 
                 inits = list(list(mu=2), list(mu=-2)))

jm2$state()
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$mu
# [1] 2
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$mu
# [1] -2
```